# mysql throws Unknown column 'mac' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, wso2

```
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException:  Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:    Unknown column 'mac' in 'field list' ([driver]/driver.js#32)
```

I encounter this error in Wso2 EMM 1.1.0 after upgrading from 1.0.0

did anyone face this issue while migrating mysql db for wso2emm_db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with the mysql.sql script for devices table and it has been reported in the  [public JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-684) . In `<PRODUCT_HOME>/dbscripts/emm/mysql.sql`, change the field `wifi_mac` for devices table to `mac` as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_id` longtext,
  `os_version` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties` text,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `byod` smallint(6) DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `vendor` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `udid` VARCHAR(4096) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `push_token` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  **`mac`** varchar(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: but after altering the column, now it throws " Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 6b8a18b9-1da8-4908-9b46-0a1a6eeadaa8. Governance artifact Amazon already exists at /sites/admin/Amazon/1.0.0
" error

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. It works and the new error is regardless of our changes to COLUMN NAME. Am gonna accept your answer @Nira

Comment: @Manoj: This happens when the server tries to create an artifact which already exists. Can you tell me when you are getting this error? also try restarting the server and let me know if this issue happens.

Comment: I got this error when I started my server after changing the column name to mac. I restarted it in the morning it still threw error. But error vanished when I restarted my server this time.

Comment: New Warning encountered now are - 
"(1) - Could not find the handler class org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyHandler. This handler will not be registered. All handler and filter classes should be in the class path of the Registry.
"(2) -{org.wso2.carbon.stratos.landing.page.deployer.LandingPageWebappDeployer} -  Product landing page not found.

Comment: @Manoj: EMM comes with enterprise store (ES). Governance artifact error is an Intermittent issue when loading the sample artifacts (and can be removed) in ES.

Comment: @Manoj: You can ignore the warning and go ahead. Are you testing this in your local machine?

Comment: @Manoj: I have created a public JIRA[1] for the warning message that you have mentioned above.

[1] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-692